# Dúvida sobre operador de decremento

Tags: php

Tenho essas 2 linhas na minha função, mas o que seria a linha abaixo?

```
$idade--;
```

Só o return não ia ser a mesma coisa?

```
$idade--;
return $idade;
```

Só queria entender para que seria esta linha. Não gosto de usar algo que não sei pra que serve.

[Código completo](http://krebscode.eti.br/pt_BR/funcao-para-calcular-idade-em-php/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Só o return não ia ser a mesma coisa?

**Não!!!**

O `$idade--` subtrai `1` do valor de `$idade`. Equivale a:

```
$idade = $idade - 1;
```

Portanto, se você retirar o `$idade--`, o valor retornado pela sua função será sempre `1` a mais do que ela retorna hoje.

Se quiser, pode até fazer ambas as coisas na mesma linha, mas aí precisaria usar `--$idade` em vez de `$idade--`:

```
return --$idade;
```

Isso porque o `--` no final primeiro devolve o valor (atual) da variável, e depois decrementa. Já no começo ele primeiro decrementa e depois retorna. O mesmo é válido para os operadores de incremento `++` (no início ou no final).

Comment: `$idade = $idade -1`, sem o `m`, não?

Comment: @CaioFelipePereira Ops, valeu, eu não tinha visto.

Comment: Disponha. Estamos aí pra isso

Comment: Entendi a função agora, thank

Comment: Todo ano ele soma +1, $idade-- faz ele -1 se o mês não passou e etc.

Answer (score 4):

Assumindo que `$idade` é um inteiro, `$idade--` é igual a `$idade = $idade - 1`, assim como `$idade++` é `$idade = $idade + 1`.

Isto é um operador de decremento. Veja mais no [manual](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.increment.php) do PHP

Comment: Tentei buscar algo no manual, mas sem saber o nome é difícil, obrigado.